# Implement a recurring task with a background process since your function operates asynchronously

Tags: hangfire

I'm trying to run `RecurringJob` with Hangfire. This method is async method and Hangfire doesn't accept await.
the solution is to create recurring task hold background task but it's not working, it's throws an exception.

```cs
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), () => _backgroungJobClient.Enqueue(() =>_jobServices.SyncRecords()), Cron.Daily);
```

Exception

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Anonymous functions, delegates and
> lambda expressions aren't supported in job method parameters: it's
> very hard to serialize them and all their scope in general

I want to run a `RecurringJob`  and call an async method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RecurringJob` wrong! Your registration of recuring job should look like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), () =>_jobServices.SyncRecords()), Cron.Daily);
```

You don't have to worry about `async`, `await` when doing the creation of hangfire job. `RecuringJob.AddOrUpdate()` does nothing but saves definition (serialized) of your job to database.

Later the hangfire server does the activation of the job using `JobActivator` - if your method is `async` it would be used as `async` you don't have to worry about that.

Hope this helps.